# Await statement execution completion in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

In my tests, I've got some database actions that aren't exposed as `Future`s at the test level. Sometimes, my tests run fast enough that `close()` in my cleanup happens before those database actions complete, and then I get ugly errors. Is there a way to detect how many statements are in-flight or otherwise hold off `close()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query you get `Future[A]` where `A` is the result of the query.

You can compose all your queries using `Future.sequence()` to get a single future `composedFuture` which will be completed when all your queries have returned result.

Now you can use `composedFuture.map(_ => close())` to make sure that all queries have finished execution and then you close the resource.

Best option is to expose the actions as future and then compose them.
Otherwise you can put `Thread.sleep(someSensibleTime)` and hope your future completes within `someSensibleTime`, but this will make your tests slow and errorprone.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that my API needs to return one of two `Future`s, letting the other query be fire-and-forget. I think at the end of the day, I need to just rethink that API.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be database-dependant rather than slick-dependant.

For example, mysql technologies allow you to see currently running queries with the query "show processlist", and act accordingly.

If that's not an option, I suppose that you could poll the db to observe a selected side effect, and close() afterwards ?